# pandas dataframe count unique list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If the type of a column in dataframe is `int`, `float` or `string`, we can get its unique values with `columnName.unique()`.
But what if this column is a list, e.g. [1, 2, 3].
How could I get the `unique` of this column?

Comment: take the values and flatten it

Comment: Do you then want to know the unique elements per list or whether the entire lists are unique?

Comment: I want to get the unique  lists instead of unique values in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can convert values to tuples and then `unique` works nice:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[[1,1,2],[2,1,3,3],[1,1,2],[1,1,2]]})
print (df)
            col
0     [1, 1, 2]
1  [2, 1, 3, 3]
2     [1, 1, 2]
3     [1, 1, 2]

print (df['col'].apply(tuple).unique())

[(1, 1, 2) (2, 1, 3, 3)]

L = [list(x) for x in df['col'].apply(tuple).unique()]
print (L)

[[1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: Sorry for that, maybe my description is not clear. I want to get the unique lists, not the unique values in this column.

Comment: OK, can you create sample data - 5 rows with expected output?

Comment: For example, if column 'col' is [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3]], then the result should be [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]].

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply `unique()` on a non-hashable type such as list. You need to convert to a hashable type to do that.

A better solution using the latest version of pandas is to use `duplicated()` and you avoid iterating over the values to convert to list again.

```
df[~df.col.apply(tuple).duplicated()]
```

That would return as lists the unique values.

Comment: Yeah, That looks more efficient.